# Ruby on Rails add confirmation to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application and I have generated some scaffold.
I want to add a confirmation box (like the one that pops up when you delete an element) to a custom link I created.

The syntax for the element deletion is the following:

```
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

This is my custom link:

```
   <td><%= link_to 'set done', :controller => 'users', :action => 'set_donation_done', :user => user, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %><td>
```

The problem is that the confirmation box on my custom link does not appear. If I inspect the element I see the following html code:

```
<a href="/set_donation_done?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Are+you+sure%3F&amp;user=71">set done</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 <td><%= link_to 'set done', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'set_donation_done', :user => user}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}  %><td>
```

Whit this formula I have my user data in params and I can see the confirmation box!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
<%= link_to 'set done', { controller: 'users', action: 'set_donation_done' }, user: user, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Remember:

```
link_to(body, url_hash, html_hash)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thank you, but there is another problem, with your code I see the confirmation box but there is no more "user" params and I get the following error: "Couldn't find User with 'id'=". If I try to print params in the console I get the following: {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"set_donation_done"}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the controller action hash. Simply show when the HTML hash starts like so:
 `<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete,{ data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }} %></td>`